# why records are not functions?

Tags: clojure

Unlike maps, records are not functions. Why?

```
;; maps are functions of the keys
({:a 1} :a) ;; 1
({:a 1}) ;; error
({:a 1} 1) ;; nil

;; records? no, records are not functions
(defrecord T [t])
((->T 1) :t) ;; error: T cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
(:t (->T 1)) ;; 1
```

Comment: actually, Rich Hickey commented on this on his "Maybe not" [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR5WdGrpoug), specifically starting around the 17:40 [mark](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR5WdGrpoug&t=17m40s) on the video (goes on for about 3 mins). I did not quite make out what the answer to this question is from Rich's comments, though.

Answer (score 5):

Others have answered this, but here's how you make one of your defrecord types implement the IFn interface:

```
user> (defrecord Blah
          [x y]

        clojure.lang.IFn
        (invoke [o arg] (arg o)))

user> (let [obj (->Blah 1 2)]
        [(obj :x) (obj :y)])
[1 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

In [*`deftype` and `defrecord`*](https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_deftype_and_defrecord), Rich writes "*defrecord provides a complete implementation of a persistent map ...*". So records ought to work as functions?

NO. [`IPersistentMap`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentMap.java), the interface for persistent maps, does not implement `IFn`, the interface for Clojure functions.

However, consistency would be nice: converting maps to records ought to produce as few surprises as possible. Having said that ...

- We use records only where the keys are known keywords, hence the
  keyword-as-function syntax has always been available.
- Creating a record is nothing like creating a map. This is a bigger
  inconsistency, I think.

I hope this meandering maundering helps.

Comment: so, is the issue an oversight or by design? If the latter, what are the reasons?

Comment: @beluchin I'd guess it's an oversight. [Inostidal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535156/1562315) shows it's not a big problem.

Comment: _consistency would be nice: converting maps to records ought to produce as few surprises as possible_. It would indeed. That lack of consistency costed me (a rookie) some time when I turned a map into a record.